# Reinstalled Windows lost access to mshtml.dll

Tags: vb.net, mshtml

I had to reinstall Windows 7 (x64) due to a crashed disk.  When I reopened the project i was working on, and tried to compile it, I got the following error:

Unable to find source file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll' for assembly 'Microsoft.mshtml.dll'

I looked and there is of course no directory by that name on my machine.  I found this thread

[How to add a reference to mshtml version 9 in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533824/how-to-add-a-reference-to-mshtml-version-9-in-net)

but i am not sure it applies.  I cannot find anything using  "where tlbimp.exe".  I have a backup of mshtml.dll which I recovered from my failed disk.  Can I just copy it over and use it?  Do I need to register it?  Also, if I don't have it, what did I do different on this machine - could I have more/other problems later? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, it was caused by changing from windows 32 to windows 64 because the path to the dll files is different.  To fix just delete the reference and re-add it and it puts in the right path.  Worked for me anyway :-)

ChrisP.